# Dynamically append SKAction with unknown number - dependant on previous actions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm building a turn based game with SpriteKit. It's a human player versus 1+ CPU opponents.

During the CPUs' turns I'm using an `SKAction.sequence` in order to show what the CPU is doing. This usually consists of a `wait` action followed by a custom `SKAction.run` block.

Now part of the problem I have is that the CPU could perform multiple **attack** actions per turn, but after each **attack** task I recalculate if there should be anymore attacks done, as conquering a country might open up new avenues of attack. The trouble I've got here is that I then have no way of knowing how many attacks should take place upfront, and as the initial attack itself is in a block, it doesn't know if it will generate more attacks. Thus I don't know how to add additional attack steps to my sequence.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could go about this? One thought was that I actually perform all the attacks upfront without displaying them and subsequently then just **replay** them for the benefit of the player. But I'm worried it will seem like the game is hanging in this instance.

Is there anyway I could append more SKActions midway through a running sequence?

```
       let sequence:[SKAction] = []
       let attackTasks = actions.getAttackTasks()
        if attackTasks.count > 0 {
            sequence.append(SKAction.wait(forDuration:0.5))
            sequence.append(SKAction.run {
                    //PerformAttackTask Here calls another recursive function which calculates and generates more attacks
                    self.performAttackTask(attackTask: attackTasks.first!)
                    self.combatFinished = false
            })
        }

       let sequenceAction = SKAction.sequence(sequence)
       node.run(sequenceAction)
```

Comment: Use a queue to store attacks (push one to process further, pop one to process it)

Comment: `sequence` already is a queue and I know I can loop through all my attackTasks and add them to it. This works fine. The issue I want to solve is that the outcome of the first attackTasks could actually open up new attackTasks. For instance the CPU might have such a large army that after this first attack they want to attack a new country from the country they just conquered. To do that I need to recalculate the attack tasks in the recursive function. But I don't know that until the first task has run in which case I can't add them to the sequence as it's already running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that are interested I ended up changing my approach for this moving the animations down a level to the `performAttackTask` method and recursively calling itself.

I then make use of a callback that only fires when all combat is complete to exit this loop.

This also makes use of `SKAction.run` with a completion handler to then move onto the next set of actions